# [NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this code to query core data and return the value of key, I store the value like this :

```
 NSString *newName= @"test"; 
 [newShot setValue:newName forKey:@"shotNumber"];
```

and I query like this :

```
NSManagedObject *mo = [items objectAtIndex:0];  // assuming that array is not empty
  NSString *value = [[mo valueForKey:@"shotNumber"] stringValue];
  NSLog(@"Value : %@",value);
```

I'm crashing with this message though :

> [NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance,

does anyone know where that would be coming from ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`newName` (`@"test"`) is *already* an NSString. There is no need to call `-stringValue` to convert it to a string.

```
NSString *value = [mo valueForKey:@"shotNumber"];
```

Answer (score 5):

I often times add a category for NSString to handle this:

```
@interface NSString(JB)
-(NSString *) stringValue;
@end

@implementation NSString(JB)
  -(NSString *) stringValue {
  return self;
}
@end
```

You can add a similar category to other classes that you want to respond this way.

Answer (score 4):

`[mo valueForKey: @"shotNumber"]` is returning a string and `NSString` (of which `NSCFString` is an implementation detail) do not implement a `stringValue` method.

Given that `NSNumber` *does* implement `stringValue`, I'd bet you put an `NSString` into `mo` when you thought you were putting in an `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

The value for the key `@"shotNumber"` is probably of type `NSString` which is just a wrapper for `NSCFString`. What you need to do, is, instead of `stringValue`, use the `description` method.

Comment: This is wrong.   Never *ever* use `description` in production code.  `description` is purely for describing an object for debugging purposes.

Comment: If you have an NSString, you don't need to call any methods to get an NSString from it.

Comment: Correct, but if his encoding methods are inconsistent, then you should use some method to ensure that it becomes a NSString, maybe `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mo valueForKey:@"shotNumber"]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could also get this problem if you are trying to access a string property on an object that you *think* is something else, but is actually a string.

In my case I thought my Hydration object was in fact a hydration, but checking its class via `isKindOfClass` I found that it was an NSString and realized that I had incorrectly cast it as a Hydration object and that my problem lied further up the chain.